# Apache Spark 1.6.1 - OutofMemory Errors when joining 2 large files

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory

We are using Beam SDK to run Apache Spark programs. Beam calls Spark framework internally for joins and groupbykey. We are getting OutOfMemory errors when doing joins and group by key.
Could you please provide us suggestions on how we can fix the issue.

Issue:
OutofMemory Errors

**Use Case:**

1) Join 120 GB with 10GB file

Our Cluster configuration with restriction:

8 Nodes with each Node and the Max Executor memory we can set is 7GB . 
Each and every Node has a max of 80GB.
Total number of core :192 Cores
2) Spark Submit command used:

```
./spark-submit  --class com.service.Employee --master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 5G --executor-memory 7G --executor-cores 3 --num-executors 50  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024  --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=300 --conf spark.default.parallelism=300  --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer  /hadoop/project.jar
```

2) 
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

```
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1897)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readValue(Serializer.scala:171)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:201)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:198)

at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)

at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)

at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)

at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)

at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)

at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:152)

at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:45)

at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:89)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:98)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
```

Comment: Please share code

Comment: Try giving more memory to each exucutor and use less number of exuctor instances.

Comment: @morfious902002 - Please check code for LeftOuterJoin which in turns uses Spark SDK in the background.https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/join-library/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.java 2) We are getting OutOfMemory inside groupbyKey() method in the following code. https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/spark/translation/GroupCombineFunctions.java

Comment: @ Hitesh Goyal - The executor memory is restricted to 7GB. I will reduce the number of executors. Is the 50 executors I am specifying is executed across all the 50 nodes?. When I use 50, I am using 150 cores in the CPU since I specify executor-cores as 3, SO I get better CPU utilization. Checking if reducing the number of executors will decrease CPU utilization. I am thinking CPU utilization = no of executors * no of  executor-cores.